# Reference format that write 'and' instead of '&' and also indents the lines after the first

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a thesis. Please which bibliography style will write `and` instead of `&` and also indents the lines after the first in each references. I am using bibliography style `bbs`.

```
\bibliographystyle{bbs}
%\bibliographystyle{siam}
%\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{references}
```

Answer (score 3):

`apalike` seems to be the right choice:

> [Fanty et al., 1993] Fanty, M., Schmid, P., and Cole., R. (1993). City name recognition 
>       over the telephone. In Proc. International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal 
>       Processing, volume I, pages 549-552, Minneapolis, U.S.A.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain some of the special (quirky?) features of the BBS citation style while modifying the dreaded `\&` connector particle to `and`, you could

1. make a copy of the file `bbs.bst` (located in `.../bibtex/bst/beebe`) to, say, `mybbs.bst`;
2. edit the new file as follows: change the two occurrences of the string `{ " \& " * t * }` to `{ " and " * t * }` (lines 254 and 283 in my copy of the file); and
3. run `texhash` (or the equivalent command on your TeX system).

From then on, you should be able to use the command `\bibliographystyle{mybbs}`.

Comment: I think you mean `\bibliographystyle` here rather than `\usepackage`.

Comment: Absolutely!! I'll fix this right away!